# Authentication to ACR1255U-J1 reader via bluetooth React Native or Android or example

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, acr122

Anyone can help me with a example about how to integrate it!
from scratch!

Comment: Have you looked at the manual? https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/7664/REF-ACR1255U-J1-1.13.pdf The most interesting bit starts at page 19. There you have a description of the used Services and Characteristics. An example on how to connect to and read from/write to a characteristic can be found for many many languages all over the internet, for example https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/

Comment: The documentation is very tricky, and the most tutorials are related to flomio SDK, i'm looking for a step by step how to use this device via ble. can you help me? before you worked with this device?
text me at: +57 3003140528
I just need a minimalistic guide about the required data stream and order to use her services thank u!

Comment: I never worked with this specific device. I'm not willing to give you a step by step guide other, there are many out there covering the general usage of BLE. There are also android example projekts provided by the manufacturer: https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/403/acr1255u-j1-secure-bluetooth%C2%AE-nfc-reader/#downloads